# Fatal error in product detail page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, product-page

I am using **Magento 2.3.3**

I am getting below fatal error in product detail page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Config\ReaderInterface in /chroot/home/a9bd6b11/demo2.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /chroot/home/a9bd6b11/demo2.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /chroot/home/a9bd6b11/demo2.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /chroot/home/a9bd6b11/demo2.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'reader', 'Magento\\Widget\\...') #3 /chroot/home/a9bd6b11/demo2.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\Ob in /chroot/home/a9bd6b11/demo2.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

This error seems to be coming in the product detail page only all other pages are working fine. I have tried many things to solve this issue but I am not able to solve it.

I had tried enabling the production mode. I had deleted the `generated/code` folder tried running upgrade and compile command but no luck.

Can anyone help look into this issue ?

Comment: Any custom extension connect with that page?

Comment: @Rohan No, there are no extensions related to the product page.

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya
Are you able to find solution for this?

Comment: @ParthThummar No I think not